# Exception handling with try finally alone

Tags: c#

I found the following question and answer in one of the sites. My question is finally block will always be executed right? Then why do they say b as answer? Could someone please help me in understanding this?

Choose the correct output for given set of code:

```
class Program
  {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {            
          try 
          {
              Console.WriteLine("csharp" + " " + 1/0);
          }
          finally
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Java");            
          }
          Console.ReadLine();
      }
  }
```

Possible answers:

```
a) csharp 0
b) Run time Exception generation
c) Compile time error
d) Java
```

Answer : b
Explanation : Run time Error of division by zero

Comment: "*Then why do they say b as answer?*" what is this mysterious "b" you speak of?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Read on...

Comment: "However, if the exception is unhandled, execution of the finally block is dependent on how the exception unwind operation is triggered." - [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx) are normally a good place to start your research.

Comment: The correct answer is actually c - the code doesn't compile. Surely you could have checked that for yourself though.

Comment: @JonSkeet : Your eyes are compilers.

Comment: @mybirthname: Um, yes, you can *absolutely* have a try/finally block with no catch. The only compiler error here is due to the division by constant 0.

Comment: hmm okay my bad. What is the point of try/finally, is the finally block going to be executed even if the exception is not catch ? I will try it by myself anyway.

Comment: @mybirthname [Read the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx), they're very helpful...

Comment: @DavidG thanks I remember somehow in the past that you can't have finally without catch. I never used, thanks for the link the return;break; continue stuff was interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the C# 5.0 compiler I get this compilation error, so the program doesn't compile at all:

> `Console.WriteLine("csharp" + " " + 1/0);`
>   (17:50) Division by constant zero

If I change the program to use a runtime-determined value of zero, then I get the output "Java":

```
Int32 zero = 1;
try 
{
    zero = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("csharp" + " " + 1/ zero );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is c.

The C# compiler (helpfully) emits a **compilation failure** when it attempts to compile the *compile time evaluable constant expression* `1 / 0`.

(In C and C++ the behaviour on encountering `1 / 0` is *undefined*.)

As an aside, note that C# *will* compile the floating point expression `1.0 / 0` to `+Inf`.

Answer (score 0):

Because try has no catch statement so exception will be thrown anyway.
Exception occurs because your code has a divide by 0 operation 1/0

Comment: Well, it would if the code compiles - but it doesn't.

Comment: That won't be an exception, but compile time error.

Comment: He probably missed something from the provided code

Answer (score 0):

In try-catch-finally one of these scenarios will happen:

1- Try executes. No error happens and finally executes.

2- Try execution hits an error. Controller falls to catch. Runs catch code which by default is throw and finally executes after that.

So by default your code is like this:

```
class Program
  {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {            
          try 
          {
              Console.WriteLine("csharp" + " " + 1/0);
          }
          catch
          {
              throw;
          }
          finally
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Java");            
          }
          Console.ReadLine();
      }
  }
```